# Game Design. Question about balance progression

Tags: mathematics, game-design, balance

Playing in the main mode, the player receives Glory for victory, and for defeat, loses it. When the player reaches the required number of Glory, he moves to the next League. There are N Leagues in the game.
Each League has a recommended Promotion (level) of the Hero. When a player has a Hero's Promotion below the recommended one, he loses more often. The Hero has K Promotions.

And Quastion
Player must complete N Leagues for 360 days. How can i reach this?

Comment: How do you determine win/losses? Is that a multi-player game? Also, a player can have 10 Glory, then on an unlucky lost streak go back to 2 Glory? If so, when it happens, are they kicked back to the previous League? You want a player to experience the content in one year, how long do you expect they'll be playing on average? If I grind 10 hours a day, do I get there faster than if I play 10 hours per week?

Comment: You also don't mention how Promotion works.

Comment: I'm not clear on what the question actually is here. "How can I reach this?"—how can you reach what exactly? This sounds like it might be a math homework question more than a game design question.

Comment: I've voted to close this as there are too many holes in your game's description for us to fill in the blanks. Please provide more details about your game so that we can reopen the question and help you figure out a proper way to go.

Comment: I really hope this question gets fixed, because it might actually be quite interesting. But in its current state it's unfortunately unanswerable.

Comment: Welcome to the Game Development Stack Exchange. I would appreciate more on-topic game design questions on our stack and hope that you consider editing your question to include the information requested in the other comments. And if you don't, I wish you good luck on your game.

Comment: This questions is completely on topic.  I don't know why people are saying it's not.  It's problem is that none of us can understand what Neverblom means exactly, no offense.  If he can edit it so it's more understandable, it will be just fine.